# PHP permutation of if statements conditions

Tags: php

I am trying to create an advanced search function with this part of code

```
// search.php?name= &country= &city= &age= &gender=
$search_name = 0;
$search_country = 0;
$search_city = 0;
$search_age = 0;
$search_gender = 0;
$allow_query = false;

if((isset($_GET["name"])) AND ($_GET["name"] != "")) {
 $name = $_GET["name"];
 $search_name = 1;
  }

 if((isset($_GET["country"])) AND ($_GET["country"] != "")) {
 $country = $_GET["country"];
$search_country = 1;
 }

 if((isset($_GET["city"])) AND ($_GET["city"] != "")) {
 $city = $_GET["city"];
 $search_city = 1;
  }

  if((isset($_GET["age"])) AND ($_GET["age"] != "")) {
  $age = $_GET["age"];
   $search_age = 1;

  $age = date('Y', strtotime('-'.$age.' years'));
  }

  if((isset($_GET["gender"])) AND ($_GET["gender"] != "")) {
  $gender = $_GET["gender"];
  $search_gender = 1;
  }
```

But, to get rid of all these ifs....

```
 if (($search_name==1) AND ($search_country==1) AND ($search_city==1) AND ($search_age==1) AND ($search_gender==1) ){

}else if(($search_name==1) AND ($search_country==0) AND ($search_city==0) AND ($search_age==0) AND ($search_gender==0) ){

 }
```

.....and so on.... = 32 if statements

i have used switch case function in this format:

```
 switch($search_name . $search_country . $search_city . $search_age . $search_gender) {
 case 11111 : 
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM users WHERE `username` LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' OR  `country` LIKE '%" . $country .  "%' OR `city` LIKE '%" . $city .  "%' OR `birth_month` LIKE '%" . $age .  "%' OR `sex` LIKE '%" . $gender .  "%' ");
  $allow_query = true;
   break;
    case 11110 :  
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM users WHERE `username` LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' OR  `country` LIKE '%" . $country .  "%' OR `city` LIKE '%" . $city .  "%' OR `birth_month` LIKE '%" . $age .  "%' ");
    $allow_query = true;
   break;
```

and so on with 32 cases

Do you know any other method to make it look nicer or to write it easier supposing that i have hundreds of combinations?

Comment: Because of the cases starting with 0 in front of a number, there was an error. I changed 0 with 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to allow for `and`/`or` variations, just build an array of options an implode to your final sql:

```
$options = array();
if( ... do city search) {
   $options[] = '`city` LIKE "$name"';
}
if( ... do country search ) {
   $options[] = '`country` LIKE "$name"';
}
etc...

$where_clause = implode(' OR ', $options);

$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE $where_clause";
```

Note that you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Alternatively, you could also use a `fulltext` search, and only search the specific fields you need:

```
if (...city search) {
   $fields[] = 'city';
}
etc...
$field_list = implode(', ', $fields);

$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE MATCH($fields) AGAINST '$name'"
```